# Tizen Studio Fails to install

Tags: java, tizen, tizen-studio

I tried to install Tizen Studio 5.0 on my Windows 11 PC. I noticed the installer shows up but when it says "the installation process is starting..." it disappears.

I tried looking into the temporary files and ran installer.jar using

```
java -jar installer.jar
```

but I got an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.tizen.installer.exception.IMFatalException: Cannot find the config file.
        at org.tizen.installer.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:138)
        at org.tizen.installer.util.Log.getLogger(Log.java:144)
        at org.tizen.installer.ui.wizard.WizardUIMain.<clinit>(WizardUIMain.java:68)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for asking it.
We have not supported windows11 on TizenStudio officially till now
But we will check the issue as soon as possible, and then, once we find out something, we will update it again.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it was a bug in all versions of windows! are there any workarounds for it so far?

Comment: edit: please remind me when the update comes out for win11 support.

Comment: There is also some Java issue with the package manager. When I try to install Extras->TV Extensions 6.5->Emulator this error is logged:
`org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen Studio package.
 at org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.wrapExceptionWithGeneralInstallException(InstallController.java:583) ~[PackageManagerV2-cli.jar:2.1.6]...`